# Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse because of empty speech response

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am trying to implement a new welcome intent for my AoG agent, but i keep getting "Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse because of empty speech response" even the rest looks good as far as i can see.

```
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    if(userId != null){

        service.getCustomerData(userId, accessToken).then(customerData =>{
            var name;
            let conv = agent.conv();
            name = customerData.item.name;

            conv.ask('We are logged in on ' + name);
            agent.add(conv);
            resolve();
        }, error => {
            errorHandler(agent,error, resolve);
        });


    }else {
        agent.add('We are not logged in');
    }
    resolve();
});
```

Any tips or tricks here? Using API V2

Comment: Can you share a bit more of your code snippet? Are you using `dialogflow-fulfillment`? Why are you returning resolve at the bottom of the snippet?

Answer (score 0):

For tips or tricks in debugging this, I suggest you check out these two posts:

- [Debugging Common Actions on Google Errors](https://medium.com/google-developers/debugging-common-actions-on-google-errors-7c8527378d27)
- [Hey Google, I Need Help With My Action](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/hey-google-i-need-help-with-my-action-8cf09714a20d)

You don't post your entire function, which would help in this case, but my guess is that you are causing an error. Checking your logs would confirm if there is an actual error.

My guess is that this set of lines are the problem:

```
        let conv = agent.conv();
        name = customerData.item.name;

        conv.ask('We are logged in on ' + name);
        agent.add(conv);
```

Specifically, I don't think you can call `add()` and pass it the conversation object. It isn't clear why you're dealing with `conv.add()` and not using `agent.ask()` directly, for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that might stumble upon this:

For me I was getting this issue because I had never added the corresponding `app.intent()`. I copy-pasted an old one that had the name of the old intent, `app.intent('favorite color', // ...etc)` when the new one had a different name (in my case `app.intent('favorite movie', // ...etc)`).